# show that $\sin{f(n+1)}\ge \sin{f(n)},\forall n\in N $

Tags: trigonometry

let $f:N^{+}\to N^{+}$, and such
$$\sin{(f(n))}=\max\{\sin{x}|x\in N^{+},10^{n-1}\le x<10^n,n\in N^{+}\}$$
show that
$$\sin{f(n+1)}\ge \sin{f(n)},\forall n\in N $$

I feel like the problem starts with the density of the sequence?Or consider him in stages

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

First, define $g(n) = \sin(f(n))$, so $$g(n) = \max\{\sin x\mid x \in \Bbb N, 10^{n-1} \le x < 10^n\}\quad \forall n \in \Bbb N^+$$
and what you want to show is that $g(n+1) \ge g(n), \forall n \in \Bbb N^+$. That removes the first needless complication in the problem statement. There is nothing here that requires $f$ itself, which - unlike $g$ - is not even well-defined by the condition.

Next, note that within $[0,2\pi]$, if $\left|x_1 - \frac\pi 2\right| < \left|x_2 - \frac\pi 2\right|$, then $\sin x_1 > \sin x_2$. So $$g(n) = \sin \left(\underset{10^{n-1} \le x <10^n}{\arg \min}\left|x\bmod 2\pi - \frac \pi 2\right|\right)$$

So, the condition $g(n + 1) \ge g(n)$ holds if and only if there is some integer between $10^n$ and $10^{n+1}$ which is at least as close to a $4k+1$ multiple of $\frac \pi 2$ as any integer between $10^{n-1}$ and $10^n$.